# How do I keep a cloth simulation from interacting with a particle emitter, while still interacting with the particles?

Tags: particles, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to work with a cloth simulation that encloses a particle system.  Unfortunately, I can't get the cloth to be deformed by the particle system, while ignoring the particle emitter (I'm also using the Molecular Script to apply physics to the particles, http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-docs/).  In this case, I created two simple cubes to illustrate the problem, a cloth simulation cube surrounding a particle emitter cube.  [Wireframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ehZ.png)

[image: Solid view]

edit - I tried setting the particles to Global and then moved the dupli-object, which solved the emitter problem, but then the cloth wouldn't interact with the particles.

edit - I also tried activating a cloth simulator on just the particle emitter.  That didn't work either, although it could be a setting I'm missing.  The cube does emit the particles and it does deform with the cloth simulation, but the particles don't interact with it. (I tried this after I uploaded the .blend file.  I will upload a new .blend if I get closer to a solution).

I've added a simple .blend file that will hopefully illustrate the issue (Molecular Script needed to see the full idea, but shouldn't be necessary to see the problem).

I was actually able to get the Molecular simulation to work properly, by taking the top off of the cloth cube.  I didn't include those settings in this .blend file though.  For those that might download this one, the settings are really off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

1. Add a loop cut right in between the cube (cloth).
2. Delete the following lines:
   [image]
3. Change the "Element to Snap to" to vertex.
4. Then Extrude the following highlighted lines towards the middle while stopping at each loop cut:
   [image]

If all steps are done correctly the bag should open up like this:
[image: a]

NOTE: The more lines you delete in step 2 the wider the bag will open up.

BTW Here is the solved file:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @Grimlock.  Unfortunately, the cloth simulation still interacts (deforms to, or gets hung up on) the particle emitter (cube, in this case).  I'm hoping the cloth cube will be able to move freely, while it's still being deformed by whatever particle system is inside of it.

Comment: You have collision on in the physics tab taking that off stops the cube from interacting with the cloth

Comment: But to have it fall and open you will have to do the above steps and rotate the sphere so that the cut faces upwards

Comment: You could just give the emitter cloth physics so they both fall at the same time